# Increasing number of downvotes from low-rep users

Tags: discussion, downvotes

Roughly since the beginning of this year I'm seeing an increasing number of downvotes on answers of mine. Nothing drastic, but noticable. Downvotes can of course not be attributed directly, but when users leave comments we can infer by timestamp correlation that they were also the ones leaving the downvote.

In those instances (like [this example from today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616002/copy-file-with-relative-path/15616260#comment107305311_15616260)), the comment (and presumably also the downvote) these days practically always comes from a low-rep user and clearly shows that they did not understand the question, or how the answer solves the question.

Of course, this could be mere coincidence, but did anyone else notice this? To me it looks like an indicator for declining quality.

Comment: I ignored this problem for as long as I could, but comments are really not for extended discussion, even on Meta sites. This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209539/discussion-on-question-by-ansgar-wiechers-increasing-number-of-downvotes-from-lo). If you want to share your opinion, please post an answer.

Comment: How do you know these votes are from a user with a low amount of reputation?  Furthermore, if a user does not understand your question, isn't that a reason to issue a downvote?

Comment: @SecurityHound *"How do you know these votes are from a user with a low amount of reputation?"* I already explained that. Please go back and read my question. *"if a user does not understand your question, isn't that a reason to issue a downvote?"* No. Not the question, and much less an answer to that question. Of course people are free to vote however they like, but from a quality perspective downvotes should be cast when a question or answer is of low quality and/or factually wrong. IMHO, YMMV.

Answer (score 7):

No, I don't see any increase of downvotes.

It makes sense that users with lower rep try to provide comments with downvotes. Most higher rep users know that leaving comment with a downvote is not a good idea (despite occasional automatic prompt to leave feedback with votes).

It is very hard to see downvotes with comments as sign of "declining quality". Downvotes on answers are expensive, especially for low rep user - if they are still willing to vote and provide content I can only see it as attempt to improve quality of the site.

Don't forget that downvote also means "not useful" - blaming a user that their could not understand question or answer is not productive. Either completely ignore or review if question and/or answer can actually benefit from some edit. I.e. in case of linked question some improvement for title and possibly more details in an answer than "ropbocopy FTW" or "how to do … using powershell" could be useful.

Comment: I agree that this can be seen as an attempt to improve quality, and it probably really is. However, does it actually improve quality if an answer that arguably solves the problem in the best possible way is being marked as "not useful"?